# Hosting Multiple MongoDB Databases on the same MongoDB Instance/Cluster

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB there are the following conecpts:

A `MongoDB database` exists as a logical unit on a `MongoDB Instance` which is either a singleton or a cluster running within some number of `mongod processes` on some number of servers.

There is lots of Q&A around answering the question: `Should one run multiple production mongod processes on the same server?` to which the answer is: [`In general no.`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/configuration/#run-multiple-database-instances-on-the-same-system)

However, what about the question of having multiple production databases on the same instance?  I.e.:

1. Set up a production grade mongodb cluster,
2. Create a number of databases by doing something like

```
use someDatabase; 
db.someDatabase.insert({});
```

3.Creating a User/Role that is limited in access to `someDatabase`

The above described configuration could obviously suffer from the noisy neighbor problem (& related DoS attacks), but otherwise is the above considered a normal and standard way of providing a logical & security barrier between tenants? What are the pros/cons of doing so? If I needed to migrate one of these logical DBs to its own MongoDB instance, would that be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. **what about the question of having multiple production databases on the same instance?**

A:  It is very normal to have multiple databases on same instance.

Q2. **Creating a User/Role that is limited in access to someDatabase
the above considered a normal and standard way of providing a logical & security barrier between tenants?**

A: Database level authorization, works very effectively for limiting the user access rights on databases, it is safe to use.

Q3. **If I needed to migrate one of these logical DBs to its own MongoDB instance, would that be possible?**

A. You cannot have two databases with same name on same instance or cluster.

**(If more details required, do ask)**